# How to solve assignment problem with type constraints?

Tags: constraint, algorithms, assignment-problem

There are $n$ jobs and $m$ machines.
Assigning job $i$ to machine $j$ yields a profit of $c_{ij}$.
Each job has a type $t_i$.
Machine $j$ can take on up to $a_j$ jobs, but the number of job types must not exceed $b_j$.
How should the jobs be assigned to the machines to maximize profit?

[image]

For example, in this case, it is optimal to assign job 1 to machine 1 and jobs 2 and 3 to machine 2.

This problem can be solved with an integer programming solver, but I would like to know of any algorithms or related papers that solve this problem.

Comment: There are thousands of papers on this topic. Just run a search on Google Scholar for job-shop.

Comment: @Brannon where do you see a Job Shop here? For me, it looks like a variant of a Generalized Assignment or a Multiple Knapsack Problem

Comment: @sakuya, would you please, is it a homework problem?

Comment: @Brannon There are many papers on assignment problems, but I have not been able to find one that imposes a constraint on the number of types of job that can be assigned.
I would like to know if there is a standard name or algorithm for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some articles dealing with constraints limiting the number of job types assigned to a given machine can be found with the keywords "class constrained" or "color constraints":

- "The multiple knapsack problem with color constraints" (Dawande et Kalagnanam, 1998) [PDF](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.22.9533&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- "On Two Class-Constrained Versions of the Multiple Knapsack Problem" (Shachnai et Tamir, 2001) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/s004530010057)
- "A Column-Generation Approach to the Multiple Knapsack Problem with Color Constraints" (Forrest et al., 2006) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1287/ijoc.1040.0078) (only two types on each machine)
- "The class constrained bin packing problem with applications to video-on-demand" (Xavier et Miyazawa, 2008) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2008.01.001)
- "Class constrained bin packing revisited" (Epstein et al., 2010) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2010.04.037)
- "A special case of Variable-Sized Bin Packing Problem with Color Constraints" (Crévits et al., 2019) [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1109/CoDIT.2019.8820707) (only two types on each machine)

I'm not aware of any article studying the exact same problem as the one you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem looks like a Multi-resource Generalized Assignment Problem. Here are two papers that describe it:
[Garvish and Pirkul (1991)](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.37.6.695) and [Mazzola and Wilcox (2001)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nav.1029).

The amount of jobs $a_j$ that can be performed by a machine can be seen as available resource. And the amount of job types $b_j$ can also be seen as available resource. A job might consume both.

Adapting to their notation, you would have two resources, $|K|=2$. Then, machine $j$ consumes $a_{ijk}$ of resource $k$ when performing job $i$, and has $b_{jk}$ of resource $k$ available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
$b_j$ is a constraint on the number of different job types that can be assigned.
That is, $b_j$ is consumed only when machine j is assigned a type of job that has never been assigned to it before.

In the example above, 
1. Assume that machine 2 is initially assigned no jobs. $a_2 = 2$, $b_2 = 1$.
2. Assign job 2 to machine 2. $a_2 = 1$, $b_2 = 0$.
3. Assign job 3 to machine 2. At this point, $b_2$ is already 0, but since a job of type B has already been assigned, it can be assigned to machine 2 without consuming $b_2$. As a result, $a_2 = 0$, $b_2 = 0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize that subsequent jobs of the same type become "free".